# Where to Store sensitive data/information

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, security, c#-4.0

I have a `Two Factor Authentication` system where I need to store the Auto generated Code and the requested time in some form storage for retrieving it later purpose. I need to know what is the best way to store these sensitive information.

I was planning to use `Session` to store those sensitive information. When I googled, In some places people are telling its not recommended to use session to store sensitive information. Can any body explain why so.

Any suggestion to this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your user database is fine, it's a web app so the database should be completely hidden from end users (if properly managed).

The rest is just making sure your actual application is secure -- ie no SQL injections, no buffer overflows, proper workflows that all pass through your server side authentication engine etc.

Comment: I don't get your edit, `Session` isn't persistent, it's temporary storage. You still need to store it somewhere to retrieve it, and that's your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about your information they should be encrypted before store them in database, for more secure propose you can use HSM (Hardware security module) to do encryption and decryption for you or even you can rely on OTP (one-time password) for two factor authentication.